# Will iOS apps remain on devices if removed from app store?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

This has become kind of confusing for me...

If I remove my app from itunesconnect.apple.com,  will it remain on the devices of users who have installed it ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

> If I don't renew my membership, will my app still function for
>   customers who have already installed or downloaded it from the App
>   Store?
>
> Yes. If you do not renew your membership your app will still function
>   for customers who have already installed or downloaded it. However,
>   you will not be able to submit updates and your app will no longer be
>   available on the App Store.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/program-renewals.php)

Answer (score 0):

Yes I believe it will, my thinking behind this is that our current app is not available for iOS 5, and does not show up in the AppStore for those users, but it has not removed it from their device.

But it is still technically still in the store?

Also I think there has been some high profile cases in the media such as "Flappy Birds" which have remained behind.

Thanks